# Low framerate on simple libgdx example in desktop application

Tags: java, android, libgdx, frame-rate

I just started learning libGDX, and was following the example from http://steigert.blogspot.in/2012/02/2-libgdx-tutorial-game-screens.html (the second link on libGdx help page).

As of now, I just display a logo of 512x512. There is nothing else happening in the application but when I run the application in desktop mode,I get a FPS of 15-16. When I remove the image, I get 60fps for the blank screen. For android its even worse, I get 3-4 fps in Galaxy SL - GT-i9003 (Temple Run runs on playable speed on the device).

My laptop plays World of Warcraft without any hiccups in high quality so its baffling that such a small app would only achieve 15fps.

```
public class SplashScreen extends AbstractScreen {
    private Texture splashTexture;
    private TextureRegion splashTextureRegion;

    public SplashScreen(MyGDXGame game){
        super(game);
    }

    @Override
    public void show()
    {
        super.show();

        // load the splash image and create the texture region
        splashTexture = new Texture("splash.png");

        // we set the linear texture filter to improve the stretching
        splashTexture.setFilter( TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear );

        // in the image atlas, our splash image begins at (0,0) at the
        // upper-left corner and has a dimension of 512x301
        splashTextureRegion = new TextureRegion( splashTexture, 0, 0, 512, 382 );
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta ) {
        super.render( delta );

        // we use the SpriteBatch to draw 2D textures (it is defined in our base
        // class: AbstractScreen)
        batch.begin();

        // we tell the batch to draw the region starting at (0,0) of the
        // lower-left corner with the size of the screen
        batch.draw( splashTextureRegion, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight() );

        // the end method does the drawing
        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose()
    {
        super.dispose();
        splashTexture.dispose();
    }

}
```

Here is the relevant section of AbstractScreen class:

```
    public class AbstractScreen implements Screen {


    protected final MyGDXGame game;
    protected final BitmapFont font;
    protected final SpriteBatch batch;

    public AbstractScreen(MyGDXGame game ){
        this.game = game;
        this.font = new BitmapFont();
        this.batch = new SpriteBatch();
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor( 0f, 0f, 0f, 1f );
        Gdx.gl.glClear( GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
    }
...
}
```

And the desktop app:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();

    cfg.title = "First Game";
    cfg.useGL20 = false;
    cfg.width = 800;
    cfg.height = 480;

    new LwjglApplication(new MyGDXGame(), cfg);
}
```

MyGDXGame is as follows:

```
public class MyGDXGame extends Game {
private FPSLogger fpsLogger;

public SplashScreen getSplashScreen() {
    return new SplashScreen( this );
}


@Override
public void create() {
    fpsLogger = new FPSLogger();
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
}

@Override
public void render() {
    super.render();
    setScreen(getSplashScreen());
    fpsLogger.log();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    super.resize(width, height);
}

@Override
public void pause() {
    super.pause();
}

@Override
public void resume() {
    super.resume();
}
```

I have read so many good things about libGdx, so this issue seems baffling to me. What am I doing wrong to get such a low frame rate?

Comment: The code looks okay so far. I'd not use one SpriteBatch for every Screen, but it couldn't limit the framerate that much. Show us the `MyGDXGame` as well please. Amd try to enable GL20 and set foregroundFPS of your configuration. Which libgdx and java version do you use?

Comment: Thanks for the comment about SpriteBatch. I will add MyGDX in a bit. I am using LibGDX v0.9.9 and Java 1.7. GL20 didn't change the frame rate on Desktop and the phone doesn't support GL2.0. I ran MetalGun on both Desktop and the phone and the were cloking frame rates of 60 and 50 respectively.

Comment: There is no foregroundFPS to set in LwjglApplicationConfiguration in v0.9.9. I tried disabling vSYnc and useCPUSynch but my FPS still seems to be capped at 16 in Desktop mode. No change for Android since these settings don't affect it.

Comment: No foregroundFPS? I switched to 0.9.9 two days ago and there still was this setting. And no GL 2? Then it's one of those 0.8% dinosaur phones :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `setScreen(getSplashScreen());` in your `render()` method might be the problem. Move it to the `create()` method of `MyGDXGame`.

Right now you are switching the screen in every single frame and recreate a `SpriteBatch` every single time which is a very heavy object (see my comment to your question).

Comment: Thanks. That was stupid of me not catching the object recreation every time the screen was rendered. I moved the code 'setScreen(getSplashScreen());' to onCreate and now I am runnning at 60 FPS on both Desktop mode and on the device.